# Add subview before calling method

Tags: swift, subview

I've got a really strange problem. First my code:

```
func viewDuringLoading(){
        var tabBarSize = self.tabBarController?.view.bounds.size

        hider = UIView(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, tabBarSize!.width, tabBarSize!.height))
        hider.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)


        indicator = UIActivityIndicatorView(frame: CGRectMake(hider.bounds.width/2 - 25, hider.bounds.height/2 - 25, 50, 50))

        indicator.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.6)

        hider.addSubview(indicator)
        indicator.startAnimating()

        self.tabBarController?.view.addSubview(hider)

        checkProducts()

    }
```

As you see, I add a subview to my view and after that I call my non async method `checkProducts`. My problem now is, that the subview get added to my view after my `checkProducts` finished doing the work.

How can I resolve that problem? I've thought about using an async-thread. But it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depends what you do in `checkProgress`. Based on what you're saying, it sounds like `checkProgress` is a synchronous method that blocks the main thread, which stops your view from being added as a subview.

What does the method `checkProgress` do? What happened when you ran it asynchronously? If it blocks the main thread at all, it probably should be asynchronous regardless of whether it blocks the main thread or not.

Comment: I made my checkProducts method async and now it work. Many thanks.

Comment: Feel free to accept the answer if it works for you :)

Comment: Done. Sorry forgot it yesterday. :)